# Does it every make sense to return a "Resource" from a REST-based Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In the Javadocs for [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) it says: *"Interface for a resource descriptor that abstracts from the actual type of underlying resource, such as a file or class path resource. An InputStream can be opened for every resource if it exists in physical form, but a URL or File handle can just be returned for certain resources. The actual behavior is implementation-specific."*

But I have seen some Spring controllers that return `ResponseEntity<Resource>`. It seems to work but I have not seen this discussed in the docs.

Is this a common and acceptable idiom? Is there a better alternative available?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes.  But the benefit of ResponseEntity is that it encapsulates the response with generic details (body, headers, status).

Comment: My question is 1) why would anyone return `ResponseEntity<Resources>` instead of `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` or `ResponseEntity<InputStream>` and 2) where in Spring's docs does it say or recommend to return `Resource` types (irrespective of being wrapped inside `ResponseEntity` or not)?

Comment: I understand now.  There is no reccomendation other than simplicity.  Resource abstracts reading/writing a file but there are reasons you might want to read/write the byte stream.  1 such scenario would be for manipulating the bytes (image processing is a good exmple of this).  But to your point - there is no 'right' or 'wrong' way - Resource simplifies the code slightly though if you are only reading a file/resource.